# Why does “nslookup com” returns this IP?

Tags: dns, nslookup

I'm learning about DNS, so out of curiosity I typed:

```
nslookup com
```

And this is the output:

```
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   com.domain.name
Address: 178.254.23.10
```

I din't find any information about the IP on Google, so I opened `178.254.23.10` in the browser and it shows a default hosting software page.

`nslookup -type=NS com` says that I can get authoritative answers from `ns1.start-dns.de`.

I looked at related questions on ServerFault, but no one mentions this IP. What exactly is this? Why am I getting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you query nslookup for `com`, this is actually an unqualified host name and will not resolve, so nslookup quietly appends the default DNS suffix (in your case it is `domain.name`) before running the query.

Thus when you ask nslookup to look for `com`, it will instead look up `com.domain.name`, which resolves to 178.254.23.10

The `.name` is a top-level domain, managed by Verisign (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.name)